# How to parse an array from XML file

Tags: php, xml, api, zend-framework

I have an XML file after doing VAR_DUMP() this is what it returns

```
["EditorialReviews"]=>
      object(stdClass)#120 (1) {
        ["EditorialReview"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#121 (3) {
            ["Source"]=>
            string(19) "Product Description"
            ["Content"]=>
            string(610) "Description."
            ["IsLinkSuppressed"]=>
            bool(false)
          }
          [1]=>
          object(stdClass)#118 (3) {
            ["Source"]=>
            string(30) "Product Description"
            ["Content"]=> "Description 2"
          }
        }
```

I've never had this, this XML file has an array inside of it, how do I get only the first one? Usually I would just do

```
$this->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content
```

But that returns NULL or it doesn't show up when there's an array in there.

and

```
$this->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content[0]
```

Gives me an error

Also, I tried using php's simpleXML but it gave me an error too..

Comment: How about `$this->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[0]->Content`? Can you post the original XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$content = is_array($this->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview)?$this->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview[0]->Content:$this->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content;
var_dump($content);
```